# Group items in a way that sets of repeating values are segmented

Tags: sql, sql-server, gaps-and-islands

I have a table of arrivals and departure for a patient's stay:

```
ENC_ID    ARRIVE                  DEPART                  UNIT      LEVEL
123456789 2018-07-16 17:53:00.000 2018-07-17 06:30:00.000 ICU       TRAUMA
123456789 2018-07-17 06:30:00.000 2018-07-17 09:05:00.000 PERI OP   TRAUMA
123456789 2018-07-17 09:05:00.000 2018-07-18 09:06:00.000 ICU       TRAUMA
123456789 2018-07-18 23:14:00.000 2018-07-23 07:33:00.000 UNIT 5    NULL
123456789 2018-07-23 07:33:00.000 2018-07-23 14:57:00.000 ICU       TRAUMA
123456789 2018-07-23 14:57:00.000 2018-07-30 11:06:00.000 INTRA OP  TRAUMA
123456789 2018-07-30 11:06:00.000 2018-07-31 11:06:00.000 UNIT 5    NULL
```

I need to consolidate the records based on the groups of `LEVEL`:

```
ENC_ID    MIN(ARRIVE)         MAX(DEPART)         LEVEL
123456789 2018-07-16 17:53:00 2018-07-18 09:06:00 TRAUMA
123456789 2018-07-18 23:14:00 2018-07-23 07:33:00 NULL
123456789 2018-07-23 07:33:00 2018-07-30 11:06:00 TRAUMA
123456789 2018-07-30 11:06:00 2018-07-31 11:06:00 NULL
```

I hoping using `DENSE_RANK` to create a `SEQ` number for each `LEVEL` set that I could later use to `GROUP BY`:

```
ENC_ID    ARRIVED                 DEPARTED                UNIT     LEVEL   SEQ
159939879 2018-07-16 17:53:00.000 2018-07-17 06:30:00.000 ICU      TRAUMA  1
159939879 2018-07-17 06:30:00.000 2018-07-17 09:05:00.000 PERI OP  TRAUMA  1
159939879 2018-07-17 09:05:00.000 2018-07-18 09:06:00.000 ICU      TRAUMA  1
159939879 2018-07-18 23:14:00.000 2018-07-23 07:33:00.000 UNIT 5   NULL    2
159939879 2018-07-23 07:33:00.000 2018-07-23 14:57:00.000 ICU      TRAUMA  3
159939879 2018-07-23 14:57:00.000 2018-07-30 11:06:00.000 INTRA OP TRAUMA  3
159939879 2018-07-30 11:06:00.000 2018-07-31 11:06:00.000 UNIT 5    NULL   4
```

but `DENSE_RANK() over (partition by ENC_ID order by LEVEL)` it doesn't differentiate the `LEVEL` sets in a way that I can use:

```
ENC_ID    ARRIVED                 DEPARTED                UNIT     LEVEL   DR
159939879 2018-07-16 17:53:00.000 2018-07-17 06:30:00.000 ICU      TRAUMA  2
159939879 2018-07-17 06:30:00.000 2018-07-17 09:05:00.000 PERI OP  TRAUMA  2
159939879 2018-07-17 09:05:00.000 2018-07-18 09:06:00.000 ICU      TRAUMA  2
159939879 2018-07-18 23:14:00.000 2018-07-23 07:33:00.000 UNIT 5   NULL    1
159939879 2018-07-23 07:33:00.000 2018-07-23 14:57:00.000 ICU      TRAUMA  2
159939879 2018-07-23 14:57:00.000 2018-07-30 11:06:00.000 INTRA OP TRAUMA  2
159939879 2018-07-30 11:06:00.000 2018-07-31 11:06:00.000 UNIT 5    NULL   1
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem.  You want to know how many changes.  You can use `lag()` and a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when prev_level = level then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by enc_id order by arrived)
from (select t.*,
             lag(level) over (partition by ENC_ID order by ARRIVED) as prev_level
      from t
     ) t;
```

You can then aggregate by this value.

Note the above may not handle adjacent `NULL` values as you want.  So, a difference of row numbers might be better:

```
select enc_id, min(arrive), max(depart), level,
       row_number() over (order by min(arrived))
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by ENC_ID, level order by ARRIVED) as seqnum_l,
             row_number() over (partition by ENC_ID order by ARRIVED) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by enc_id, (seqnum - seqnum_l), level;
```

Comment: My solution was following your first approach, but I hadn't cracked the group numbering that you create with `sum(case when prev_level = level then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by enc_id order by arrived)`.  Your second approach, however, works better for my needs.  In any case, great techniques and thanks for the help!